# spark structured streaming monitor top level folder, but dynamically write to separate tables

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a s3 bucket with the structure `//storage-layer/raw/__SOME_FOLDERS__`. EG: `//storage-layer/raw/GTest` and `//storage-layer/raw/HTest`. In these folders, there is the potential to have a few other folders as well, such as `raw/GTest/abc`, `raw/HTest/xyz`. There will not be an overlap in folders `abc` and `xyz` from `GTest` or `HTest`.

I am successful in setting up a spark structured streaming to monitor `raw/GTest/abc` for `parquet` files coming in, and writing the results out to console.

```
def process_row(df, epoch_id):
    df.show()


# Structured Streaming 
(
        self.spark
        .readStream
        .format("parquet")
        .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 20)            
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .load("s3a://storage-layer/raw/GTest/abc/*")

        .writeStream
        .format("console")
        .outputMode("append")
        .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds")
        # .foreachBatch(process_row)
        .start()
        .awaitTermination()
)
```

My problem is, how can i set up 1 structured streaming app to readStream from the upper folder: `storage-layer/raw/*` do some processing on it, and save it into a completely different folder / bucket in s3?

I have taken a look at `foreachBatch` above, but i'm not sure how to set it up such that it can achieve the end result. I get the error message `Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.`

Example of end result:

- parquet files saving into s3 `storage-layer/raw/GTest/abc` -> structured streamed + processed into `storage-layer/processed/GTest/abc` as parquet file.
- parquet files saving into s3 `storage-layer/raw/HTest/xyz` -> structured streamed + processed into `storage-layer/processed/HTest/xyz` as parquet file.

Answer (score 0):

- For `Unable to infer the schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.` Spark stream cannot infer schema automatically as we see in static read. So need to provide schema explicitly for the data at `s3a://storage-layer/raw/*` programmatically or stored in an external file. [Have a look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789153/how-to-convert-avro-schema-object-into-structtype-in-spark)
- You have two different source locations so need two `readStream`. If the data at `storage-layer/raw/*` has the same schema and you want to achieve it using only one `readStream` then include an extra field as `stream_source_path` at writing process and the process which writes data at `storage-layer/raw/*` should populate this field. So now your streaming app knows from which source location data is being read and you can derive two data frames based on `stream_source_path` value from a single `readStream`.
- The above two data frames can be now written to separate sinks.
- Spark has out-of-box support for `File` sink and you want to write data in `parquet` format. So you don't need `foreach` or `foreachbatch` implementation.

Code snippet -

```scala
    val schemaObj = new Schema.Parser().parse(avsc_schema_file)
    val schema = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schemaObj).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

    val stream = sparkSession.readStream
      .schema(schema)
      .format("parquet")
      .option("cleanSource","archive")
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", "1")
      .option("sourceArchiveDir","storage-layer/streaming_source_archive/")
      .option("latestFirst", value = true)
      .load("s3a://storage-layer/raw/*")

val df_abc = stream.filter(col("stream_source_path") === "storage-layer/raw/GTest/abc")

val df_xyz = stream.filter(col("stream_source_path") === "storage-layer/raw/GTest/xyz")

df_abc.writeStream
    .format("parquet")        
    .option("path", "storage-layer/processed/GTest/abc")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "storage-layer/streaming_checkpoint/GTest/abc")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 seconds"))
    .start()

df_xyz.writeStream 
    .format("parquet")        
    .option("path", "storage-layer/processed/GTest/xyz")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "storage-layer/streaming_checkpoint/GTest/xyz")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 seconds"))
    .start()

sparkSession.streams.active.foreach(x => x.awaitTermination())
```

Comment: That's interesting. thanks for it! let me take a look. How would `checkpointing` be configured in this case?

Comment: Missed some code, updated answer. Each `writeStream` will have its own checkpoint location.