# Csv custom schema in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-csv

I have a csv file

> 1577,true,false,false,false,true

I tried to load the csv file with custom schema,

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("id", StringType, nullable = false),
      StructField("flag1", BooleanType, nullable = false),
      StructField("flag2", BooleanType, nullable = false),
      StructField("flag3", BooleanType, nullable = false),
      StructField("flag4", BooleanType, nullable = false),
    StructField("flag6", BooleanType, nullable = false))

    )
    val df =
      spark.read.schema(customSchema).option("header","false").
     option("inferSchema","false").csv("mycsv.csv")
```

But nullable properly of schema is not changing as expected.

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- flag1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- flag2: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- flag3: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- flag4: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- flag6: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: i think you need to cast as well .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526208/about-how-to-create-a-custom-org-apache-spark-sql-types-structtype-schema-object

Comment: Also see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917075/pyspark-structfield-false-always-returns-nullable-true-instead-of

Comment: thanks for the help. I got a workaround from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443483/how-do-i-apply-schema-with-nullable-false-to-json-reading?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below urls for details

> [Spark DataFrame Schema Nullable Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705602/spark-dataframe-schema-nullable-fields)
>
> [How do I apply schema with nullable = false to json reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443483/how-do-i-apply-schema-with-nullable-false-to-json-reading?rq=1)

Workaround

```
val rowDF = spark.read.textFile("mycsv.csv")
    val df= spark.read.schema(customSchema).csv(rowDF)
    df.printSchema()
```

Comment: You might need the databricks CSV library or Spark >= 2.0 to do that

Answer (score 0):

> // Create an RDD val rowRDD1 =
>   spark.sparkContext.textFile("../yourfile.csv")
>
> // The schema is encoded in a string val schemaString = "id flag1
>   flag2 flag3 flag4 flag5 flag6"
>
> // Generate the schema based on the string of schema val fields =
>   schemaString.split(" ").
>                map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
>
> val schema = StructType(fields)
>
> // Convert records of the RDD (rowRDD1 ) to Rows val rowRDD = rowRDD.
>                map(_.split(",")).
>                map(attributes => Row(attributes(0), attributes(1),..,..))
>
> // Apply the schema to the RDD val rowDF =
>   spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)